# Use of `?` in a JavaScript timer function return

Tags: javascript

So I stumbled on some Javascript timer example and there was this function, which gets a number into it and then the function returns the time:

```
function timer(variable){
   return variable > 9 ? variable : "0" + variable;
}
```

And the whole code would look something like this:

```
var sec = 0;
function timer(variable){
    return variable > 9 ? variable : "0" + variable;
}
setInterval(function(){
    $("#time-id").val("Minutes: "+timer(parseInt(sec/60, 10))+" Seconds: "+timer(++sec%60));
}, 1000);
```

So yes, the `setInterval` function is pretty clear to me but about the `timer()`.

What is the usage of `?` in it? And how does it understand if I have multiple params given to it. Should it not be marked like this : `timer(variable1, variable2){}` ?

Comment: that's called a ternary operator. see : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: In your example there aren't any "multiple params" to understand.

Comment: Technically, it's called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator); people sometimes refer to it as the ternary operator because it's the only ternary (three-argument) operator in most languages and many books call it the "ternary ?:" operator -- which should be read as "ternary conditional operator".

Comment: Well timer(parseInt(sec/60, 10)) is sending in two params ?

Comment: No, `parseInt` returns one value and that value is sent in for the param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timer is formatting time so that if it is 6:05, it shows up as 6:05 and not 6:5

```
return variable > 9 ? variable : "0" + variable;
```

is the same as

```
if ( variable > 9 ) {
    return variable
} else {
    return "0" + variable
}
```

Comment: Also can add zero's like this: `var result = "00".slice("6".length) + "6");`

Comment: Thanks! I think I will be preferring to use the latter one. The first one just doesen't look so good to me.

Comment: Its also the same as `variable > 9 && variable || "0" + variable`

Comment: Should be noted that if you run the if|else statement through google's closure compiler, it will output with a ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

[`?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) is an operator shared by a lot of modern languages. It's a shortcut for an `if` test. The structure is as follows :

```
condition ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse
```

In your case, it appends a 0 to your variable if the variable is < 10. You could read it as :

```
if (variable > 9)
     do nothing
else
     add a "0" before
```

Answer (score 2):

It's saying that if `variable` is 10 or more, it just echoes back `variable`; otherwise it adds a 0 on the start to still make it two digits.

Answer (score 2):

`variable > 9 ? variable : "0" + variable;` is a ternary expression. `variable > 9` is evaluated, and if it's truthy, `variable` is returned, otherwise `"0" + variable` is returned. Think of it as a one-liner substitute for an `if-else` statement with assignment.

Comment: Actualy `?:` is the operator, that whole string is an expression.